# Plot word-frequency in table in R

Tags: r, plot, word-frequency

I have a data.frame/table with a timestamp and a title. I want to make a plot which shows how often a word is used in a week. Generating weeks works.

```
      |
|     |           |
Week1 Week2 Week3 Week4 etc
1x    2x    0x    1x
```

I added a column with `cbind(table, newcol = "filterword")` and tried to use `filter(str_detect(titlecolumn, "filterword"))` to put the word in the newcol when it's used in titlecolumn.

```
library(RMariaDB)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplot)
library(sparklyr)
library(tidytext)
library(base)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)

ergebnis <- dbFetch(res)

ergebnis2 <- (cbind(ergebnis,  Hour = hour(ergebnis$a_timestamp)))
ergebnis2 <- (cbind(ergebnis2, Week = round_date(ergebnis$a_timestamp, "week")))

# something like this...
# cbind(table, newcol = filter(str_detect(titlecolumn, "filterword")))

plot(ergebnis2$Week, ergebnis2$Hour)

print(ggplot(data = ergebnis2) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = ergebnis2$Week, y = ergebnis2$Hour)))
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can share a sample of what your data looks like, e.g. by including the output of `dput(head(ergebnis))` and `dput(head(ergebnis2))` in the body of your question.

Comment: BTW, you may get unexpected results if you use `ergebnis2$Week` in your ggplot call -- you should use `Week` and `Hour` instead.